# Github with AWS EC2 CodeDeploy

Tags: github, amazon-ec2, codeigniter-3

I got a codeigniter(3.x) website running on a EC2. I have seen how easy it is to link Azure with Github to push code from the repository (when updates are committed and pushed).

Did look everywhere but I couldn't find any thing that just link Github with EC2 for PHP code push. All integrations I found ran compilation commands. I just need to push file as they get updated on Git.

Much appreciate if you could share some info on this.

Comment: I too am considering how to best implement a simple git deploy when the repo is updated and came across this: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/automatically-deploy-from-github-using-aws-codedeploy/

Comment: Hi John...did this work for you? I didn't have any luck

Comment: Haven't gotten to it yet. Will share when I do.